# Haskell: a function returning the last element of a list as a Maybe Just or Nothing on empty list

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

I have this simple function:

```
myLast :: [a] -> Maybe a
myLast xs = foldr lastHelper Nothing xs
```

The idea is that it returns `Just x` on an non-empty list with the last element `x`. If the list is empty, `Nothing` is expected.

Now, I am missing the definition of `lastHelper` (the above `myLast` *must* remain intact (this is homework)).

I tried to solve this cipher for hours now, to no avail. How should I go about defining `lastHelper`?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you having trouble?

Comment: The best way is to figure out what's the type of `lastHelper`. From there is easy to go. Hint: you can also check function `(<|>)` from `Control.Applicative`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When all else fails, expand a few cases and figure them out by hand:

`foldr lastHelper Nothing []` is `Nothing` by definition of `foldr`.

Then,

```
    foldr lastHelper Nothing (1::[])
--> lastHelper 1 (foldr lastHelper Nothing [])
--> lastHelper 1 Nothing [By definition of foldr]
--> We wish this to be Just 1, so decide that it is.
```

```
    foldr lastHelper Nothing (2::1::[])
--> lastHelper 2 (foldr lastHelper Nothing (1::[])
--> lastHelper 2 (Just 1) [By the previous wishful hand-expansion]    
--> Should be Just 1, as well
```

```
    foldr lastHelper Nothing (3::2::1::[])
--> lastHelper 3 (foldr lastHelper Nothing (2::1::[])
--> lastHelper 3 (Just 1) [See above]    
--> Should also be Just 1 [I sense a pattern here.]
```

Now you should be able to write down

```
lastHelper x Nothing = ???
lastHelper x ??? = ???
```

and fill in the blanks

Answer (score 3):

Consider how you might solve this recursively, without `foldr`:

```
myLast [] = Nothing
myLast (x:[]) = Just x
myLast (_:xs) = myLast xs
```

What if, instead of having to call `myLast` recursively, you could assume that `myLast` receives the result of the recursive call as an argument?

```
-- No recursion possible, so ignore the "magical" second argument
myLast' [] _ = Nothing
-- The only way to return Nothing is with an empty first argument,
-- so we can assume the tail we are ignoring is empty
myLast' (x:_) Nothing = Just x
-- If we reach this case, we assume the first list has 2 or more
-- elements. x is clearly not the last one, so the last one must be
-- the last element of the tail, is given to as as the result.
myLast' (x:_) result = result
```

Notice that *we* never care about the tail of the list here; we assume that "someone" used it to give us our second argument.

`foldr` is that someone. We derive the helper from `myLast'` by receiving only the *head* of the list as one argument, and the presumed recursive result as the second. We no longer need the first case: `foldr` itself detects the empty list (which has no head) and returns our default value without using the helper. That is, the helper *only* gets called when `myLast'` would have received a non-empty first argument.

I leave the full adaptation of `myLast'` to the helper to the reader.

```
myLast xs = foldr lastHelper Nothing xs
  where lastHelper ??? ??? = ???
        lastHelper ??? ??? = ???
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an exercise. Without lastHelper, the exercise does not pass the automated tests.

Comment: Yes, but it's *your* exercise. I don't want to just hand you the answer, but rather help explain *how* to get from a naive implementation to a `foldr`-based one. (If you can read the edit history, you'll see how to do that; I strongly encourage you *not* to do so, though, as I regret fully answering the question originally.)

Answer (score 1):

`foldr` is a catamorphism on a list. Indeed, it `foldr f z` replaces `(:)` with `f` and `[]` with `z`.

This thus means that you can let `f` inspect the second parameter. If it is a `Nothing` we know that the first parameter is the last item, if it a `Just` we know that the first parameter is not the last item, so we propagate the last one.

The function thus will look like:

```
myLast :: [a] -> Maybe a
myLast xs = foldr lastHelper Nothing xs
    where lastHelper x Nothing = …   -- x is the last item
          lastHelper x (Just y) = …  -- x is not the last item
```

where I leave filling in the `…` parts as an exercise.